# ¿Segmentation fault en Ensamblador 8086 NASM SASM?

Tags: ensamblador, nasm

Un programa escrito en lenguaje ensamblador 8086 con SASM me está tirando un error de "Program received signal SIGSEGV, SEGMENTATION FAULT" al momento de ejecutarlo

Adjunto el codigo

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data

vector db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
vectorResultado db 0
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging

MOV EDX,vector ;copio puntero de vector a EDX
MOV EBX,0 ;inicializo EBX en 0 para desplazarme sobre el vector
MOV ECX,16 ;inicializo ECX con la cantidad de valores, para poder iterar x veces
LOPEAR:
MOV AL,[EDX+EBX] ;copio el valor que se encuentra en la posicion EBX del vector en el registro de 8 bits AL
MOV [vectorResultado+EBX],AL ;copio el valor de AL en la posicion EBX del vectorResultado
ADD EBX,1     ;incremento EBX en 1 para desplazarme y leer valores de a 1 byte
LOOP LOPEAR 

MOV EBX,0
MOVQ MM0,[vector+EBX]

ret
```

Lo raro es que si en la linea que dice MOV ECX,16 la cambio por MOV ECX,12, el programa funciona sin problemas

Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

[image: Adjunto error]

[image: Adjunto cuando funciona ok]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vectorresultado` no es un vector al uso, es un único valor, y cuando intentas acceder al equivalente en código C:

```
vectorresultado[__EBX__] = al;
```

Que, en ensamblador, podría traducirse en:

```
MOV [vectorResultado+EBX],AL;
```

No puedes, porque no existe esa dirección de memoria. Que te permita con 12 o con 16 es irrelevante, porque, de funcionar, seguirías teniendo ese `segmentation fault`.